# Error in output in gaussian

Tags: gaussian

I am beginner regarding the use of Gaussian. Currently, i am trying to study the vibration of HgCl2. I have an error:  Error termination via Lnk1e in /nfs/opt/Gaussian/16.c01/avx2/l301.exe
Any help is highly appreciated, because I did not find where is the problem.

````
Stoichiometry    Cl2Hg
 Framework group  D*H[O(Hg),C*(Cl.Cl)]
 Deg. of freedom     1
 Full point group                 D*H     NOp   8
 Largest Abelian subgroup         D2H     NOp   8
 Largest concise Abelian subgroup C2      NOp   2
                         Standard orientation:                         
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      1         80           0        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
      2         17           0        0.000000    0.000000    2.430000
      3         17           0        0.000000    0.000000   -2.430000
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rotational constants (GHZ):           0.0000000           1.2237516           1.2237516
 General basis read from cards:  (5D, 7F)
 ======================================================================================================
                                       Pseudopotential Parameters
 ======================================================================================================
  Center     Atomic      Valence      Angular      Power
  Number     Number     Electrons     Momentum     of R      Exponent        Coefficient   SO-Coeffient
 ======================================================================================================
 Wanted an integer as input.
 Found a floating point number as input.
       1.96406000D+01         1.58755454D-01                                     
 ?
 Error termination via Lnk1e in /nfs/opt/Gaussian/16.c01/avx2/l301.exe at Mon Oct  2 16:44:06 2023.
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  4.0 seconds.
 Elapsed time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  0.5 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=     17 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=      2 Scr=      2
```
````

Comment: +1 Welcome to matter modelling stack exchange! If you could post the rest of the error message (and possibly the input keywords) as well, it would help in providing answers. Error termination can come from a lot of different causes so it is not exactly clear without further context.

Comment: Please add the last 20-25 lines of the Gaussian output. It is not helpful to see which link has gone wrong. Also, try to upload the input file. That helps us debug if there is something wrong.

Comment: Probably the problem of basis set assignment. Not sure though, as it seems that the input file is also required.